# How best to connect a second gas run to a meter

Tags: plumbing, gas, natural-gas

I am running a 1 1/4 gas line to the garage in the rear of my lot - total run is about 85 feet. Trench and Home-Flex underground PE pipe (https://homeflex.com/underground/#system) is already layed out as you can see in the left corner. I am trying to figure out the best way to get under the sidewalk and which way to connect it to the meter. There is a second outlet after the meter that is currently capped and my plan it to connect into it.

Questions:

1. Should I connect as shown by the green or purple route? Green will "cross" the gas supply that is shown in yellow (but will be above is as far as depth) and may also extend past the window. Esthetically, this does not feel  right. However, it give me more space to maneuver to the left of the sidewalk.
2. Purple has the benefit of not crossing the supply in the ground, but is a bit close to the sidewalk. The meter risers are pretty large (30x30 inch L) and connection point of PE coupling and gas riser will eventually have to be shifted under the sidewalk.
3. Is meter riser even needed or can just go down with black iron pipe and 90degree horizontal, go under sidewalk with black pipe and connect to Yellow pipe on the other side of the sidewalk for a long 80 foot run. If I were to do this in black pipe, I would use the purple option.
   3a) I see that all gas pipes that come from underground are painted gray and not black, what type of pipe is it and is my idea of using black gas pipe even valid.

[image]

Comment: Your location will determine local codes -- depth, requirement for inspection, licensing requirements, etc. In the end, a lot of these questions will be answerable by your local authority having jurisdiction.

Comment: You can rule out the yellow option.  Everything to the service-side of the meter including the meter itself are the gas company's property.  You cannot modify any of their equipment or installation.  As far as going under the concrete, only two options, open it up or have it bored in under the slab.

Comment: You cant use black iron pipe for underground gas line. Must be special green-dipped pipe (not just paint) and all connections and fittings must be wrapped with 20 mils. of special wrap tape.

Answer (score 1):

Meter is way too close to the window i would have the gas company come out and clean upgrade the meter to a 2psi system looks to be low pressure it up replace that frist galvi 90 on the wall with a tee with a shut off valve union and connect the second riser and pe and run to the new location

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Do you have some information to support your claims? What locale does this apply to? How can you tell that it's a "low pressure" system just by looking - what do you see that tells you this?